# AS400 SQL query for mm/yyyy from date field

Tags: sql, select, ibm-midrange

For reporting purposes, I would like to retrieve my `date(digits(mydate7))` field as `mm/yyyy`.

I have tried `month(date(digits(mydate7)) + '/' + year (date(digits(mydate7)) as mmyyyy` but get `null` as result. I can test with `month(date(digits(mydate7))` and the year function individually and get a return set of data but not combined in field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DB2/400 uses the double pipe character for concatenation:

```
RTRIM(CHAR(MONTH(DATE(DIGITS(mydate7))))) || '/' || RTRIM(CHAR(YEAR(DATE(DIGITS(mydate7)))))
```

---

Assuming `mydate7` is in the format `yyyyddd` you could simplify it as:

```
RTRIM(CHAR(MONTH(DATE(DIGITS(mydate7))))) || '/' || SUBSTR(DIGITS(mydate7),1,4)
```

Simplified further with [implicit casting](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzcastdt.htm):

```
RTRIM(MONTH(DIGITS(mydate7))) || '/' || RTRIM(mydate7/1000)
```

---

See the [concatenation operator](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzwtco.htm) for more information.

Comment: This solution seemed to work but I have about 4 spaces between 2   /2011 instead of 2/2011

Answer (score 1):

[Looks like](http://as400questions.blogspot.jp/2009/06/tutorial-as400-chapter-4-sql.html) `CONCAT` is the string concatenation function, not `+`. It's probably trying to add a numeric with a string and barfing.

Try `CONCAT(CONCAT(month(date(digits(mydate7)),'/'), year(date(digits(mydate7)))`.

Comment: Close and on the right track!  Try month(date(digits(mydate7)) concat '/' concat year (date(digits(mydate7)) as mmyyyy

Answer (score 0):

Normally i do like this

```
substr(char(mydate7,ISO),6,2) || '/' || substr(char(mydate7,ISO),1,4)
```